# background scroll and zoom

Tags: background, playn

*NOTE* I'm really new to the playN world, and taking my first step towards using this tool.

My question is when using playN what is the most effective way to create a scrolling background effect? I've thought of several ideas, but I'm wondering if there is a specific solution that playN lends itself to. The multilevel scroll and zoom shown in the playN version of angry birds is a lot like the effect I am looking for. Can anyone point me in the right direction on functions to use/ how to logically set up an effect like that? Thanks!

Comment: Your comment does not have so much to do with PlayN. It's more about smart game design in general.

Comment: That's a good insight. Your answer below is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. I understand some of the concepts of how to do it, just was wondering if there is a specific playN approach. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideas for zoom: Use the `Animator.tweenScale()` method.

For multilevel scroll you can build a solution with `Animator.tweenTranslation()`